# Selenium: Can I Assert that a click has not been done?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a DatePicker with a custom validation which makes possible to put limits for dates that can be selected (From and To)
So for example if I set a limit in DateFrom: 02/01/2018, then 01/01/2018 (1 day before) is no longer clickable. So I was wondering if there is an assertion to check that a click has not been done, or maybe you guys know a better solution for this case

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you click an invalid date? How would you manually test that the click didn't occur or behaved correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can with try-catch block in your test:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Scenario1Test.driver, 10); 
try {
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//some XPATH")));
} catch TimeoutException {
  // code if element not clickable
}
```

Comment: The better approach is, to hide this block in function e.g, to be not in test. For me, it's an "ugly" code, when you leave it in tests. You can read more about control flow in java. how to catch exceptions and etc.    HINT: in my pseudo code,  change TimeoutException with ElementNotFound or more specific and expected error, because many things can raise TimeoutException (slow internet connection and etc) :)